# JavaScript returning an answer only sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, math

I have been exploring JavaScript and been working on making a working calculator that solves quadratic equations for both answers. I have been running into the issue that sometimes the formula returns NaN when I know the real answer. Such as using 1 for b, -5 for a, and -14 for c returns "NaN, NaN" but should be 7,-2. Is there a reason for this or is there a bug in my code? Thanks in advance

```js
function quadForm() {
  var b = document.getElementById("oppb").value;
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
  var ansplsunrd = (-1 * b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
  var ansmnsunrd = (-1 * b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ansplsunrd + ", " + ansmnsunrd;
}
```

```html
<h2>Quadratic Calculator</h2>
<p class="var-1">b:</p><input type="number" class="calc-field" id="oppb" placeholder="Insert B" value="0">
<p class="var-2">a:</p><input type="number" class="calc-field" id="a" placeholder="Insert A" value="0">
<p class="var-3">c:</p><input type="number" class="calc-field" id="c" placeholder="Insert C" value="0"> <br> <br>
<button type="button" onClick="quadForm()">Calculate</button>
<p id="result">Result shown here</p>
```

Comment: I suspect that the problem is with your parsing of `a,b,c` from the webpage, not what happens when you plug them into the formula. Maybe you should explicitly convert them to numbers.

Comment: Could you elaborate, I'm afraid I'm new and my school system blocks the dev tools so JS console doesn't help me. Could you recommend how to resolve the issue?

Comment: `input.value` is a string, not a number.

Comment: The value is a string. Letting JavaScript coerce them to numbers on the fly is unreliable.

Comment: JS Math doesn't support complex numbers, so `Math.sqrt(negative)` is NaN. You have to check the sign of the discriminant and deal with complex roots yourself.

Comment: @georg yes but in the particular case that was mentioned, it should not mathematically produce a negative number as an argument to `Math.sqrt()`

Comment: @georg Oh, that is my bad. I should've remembered how we dealt with that in Algebra. I'd have to make an if statement to resolve it checking for is in Math.sqrt there is a negative and go from there? Much appreciated.

Comment: Use `a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It does. `Math.pow(1, 2) - (4 * -5 * -14)` evaluates to `-279`.

Comment: @Ivar You are right -- I took OP's claim that those values correspond to a real solution at face value.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Would something along the lines of if (discriminat < 0) { discriminant * -1 } work to reverse the sign of when the radical has a negative?

Comment: I fixed the issue as shown in my answer below. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @Ivar ah, I accidentally misread, thought it was stated as `a = 1, b = -5`, which would produce the results expected by OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to correct my errors and make my code more clean looking by adding variables for each section of the equation. I separated the process of making b opposite, division of 2a, and power of b^2-4ac. Then making an if/ else statement in the snippet. Thanks to those who pointed out the issue of a negative discriminant that is what got me here. I just need to add an "i" to the answer for accuracy.

```js
function quadForm() {
 var b = document.getElementById("oppb").value;
 var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
 var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
 var discrim = Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c);
 var divby = 2*a;
 var oppb = -1*b;
 if (discrim < 0) {
    var negrt = (oppb + Math.sqrt((discrim*-1)))/(divby);
    var posrt = (oppb - Math.sqrt((discrim*-1)))/(divby);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = negrt + "i" + ", " + posrt + "i";
} else {
    var ansplsunrd = (-1 * b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
    var ansmnsunrd = (-1 * b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ansplsunrd + ", " + ansmnsunrd;
}
}
```

```html
<h2>Quadratic Calculator</h2>
<p class="var-1">b:</p><input type="number" class="calc-field" id="oppb" placeholder="Insert B" value="1">
 <p class="var-2">a:</p><input type="number" class="calc-field" id="a" placeholder="Insert A" value="-5">
  <p class="var-3">c:</p><input type="number" class="calc-field" id="c" placeholder="Insert C" value="-14"> <br> <br>
 <button type="button" onClick="quadForm()">Calculate</button>
  <p id="result">Result shown here</p>
```

Comment: Note that you can reuse already computed vars in the else branch.

Comment: @georg Absolutely! I was just being lazy and using what I had then. I have replaced the else function with the appropriate variables.